# DataGrid column cell underline binding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am having issue binding text decoration to datagrid column DataTemplate. Here is the xaml setup.

```
<UserControl x:Class="myClass"...>

        <DataGrid 
            Name="_dataGrid"
            FontFamily="{Binding Font_Family}"
            FontWeight="{Binding Font_Weight}">

    <Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
      <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock 
                 Text="{Binding Data1}" 
                  Foreground="Red" 

                  //This binding does not work
                 TextDecorations="{Binding Decor_Underline"/> 

          </DataTemplate>
        </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </Controls:DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
    </UserControl>
```

The error i get goes something like this.

```
BindingExpression with XPath cannot bind to non-XML object.; XPath='Model.Decor_Underline' BindingExpression:Path=Decor_Underline; DataItem='DataGrid'
```

If i manually set the text decoration it works fine. `TextDecoration = "Underline"` 
The bindings for Font_Family and Font_Weight is working fine.

I have tried doing the following; But since DataGrid does not have TextDecorations property it did not help.

```
TextDecorations="{Binding Decor_Underline ,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}
```

Here is the property in the model. The event is raised as expected without no effect on the control - its as if no one is listening. The scenario is i press a button and the grid columns textbox gets underlined.

```
public TextDecorationCollection Decor_Underline {
            get { return decor_Underline; }
            set {
                if(someFlg)
                  decor_Underline = TextDecorations.Underline;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Decor_Underline");
            }
        }
TextDecorationCollection decor_Underline;
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you share the view model? What is the data type of `Decor_Underline` property?

Comment: Is `Decor_Underline` is in your `Model`?

Comment: updated the question with the binding property in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you want to create your own DataGridTemplateColumn when it contains just a TextBlock ? I have little experience with DataGridTemplateColumn, but why not use a DataGridTextColumn ? Here is a solution that works with DataGridTextColumn and maybe you can do it similarly for DataGridTemplateColumn ?

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="TextDecorationsStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    ...
    <Setter Property="TextDecorations"
      Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
      Path =Item.Decor_Underline}" />
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
...
<DataGrid ...>
  ...
  <DataGrid.Columns>
   ...
   <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Data1}" 
     ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextDecorationsStyle}"/>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

For the complete code and in detail explanation how it works see my article on CodeProject: [Guide to WPF DataGrid Formatting Using Bindings](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-Formatting-Using-Bindings) . It describes how most DataGrid formatting can be done with binding, including TextDecorations.